# Prove that if analytic function $f$ is such $f(0) \neq 0$, it has no zeroes in a certain disk

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, roots

> **Problem.** Assume $\displaystyle f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ is analytic in $\overline{U}=\{|z|\leqslant R\}$ and $a_0\ne 0$。Prove: $f$ has no zeroes in the circular disk $\left \{|z|< \dfrac{|a_0|R}{|a_0|+M}\right\}$, where $M = \max_{z\in \partial \overline U} |f(z)|$.

**My attempt:** I tried to use proof by contradiction, that is to assume $f$ has zeroes in the disk, but however I was not able to deduce the contradiction. So I guess probably it is not the right approach for this problem. Also I guess it may be related to the [*maximum modulus principle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle), which I failed to establish connections with.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1988771/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2124161/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cdfrac%7B%7Ca_0%7CR%7D%7B%7Ca_0%7C%2BM%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify your title in order that it is more "neutral".

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function $$
z \in D \longmapsto \frac{f(Rz)-a_0}{M+|a_0|}
$$ 
is an analytic function from $D$ to itself that is zero at $0$. So by Schwarz lemma 
$$
|f(z)-a_0| \leq \frac{M+|a_0|}{R}|z|.
$$

So if $f(z)=0$, then $|a_0| \leq \frac{M+|a_0|}{R}|z|$, QED.

Comment: Hi, I hope you don't mind for my edit: I like your answer very much and I tried to improve its formatting: if you don't like the result, please feel free to revert it.